# Represent an arc over letters

Tags: text-decorations

I want to have a flat arc over some letters. How is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand\bigfrown[2][\textstyle]{\ensuremath{%
  \array[b]{c}\text{\scalebox{2.4}{$#1\frown$}}\\[-1.3ex]#1#2\endarray}}

\begin{document}

\bigfrown{PQR}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `scalebox` you may use `resizebox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand\bigfrown[2][\textstyle]{\ensuremath{%
  \array[b]{c}\text{\resizebox{6ex}{.7ex}{$#1\frown$}}\\[-1.3ex]#1#2\endarray}}

\begin{document}

\bigfrown{PQR}


\end{document}
```

This is very manual and you have to adjust the parameters of `resizebox` by yourself.

## Edit:

Atleast with this code you don't have to guess the width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,calc}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\newcommand\bigfrown[2][\textstyle]{\ensuremath{%
  \array[b]{c}\text{\resizebox{\mywidth}{.7ex}{$#1\frown$}}\\[-1.3ex]#1#2\endarray}}

\begin{document}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{PQRSPQ}
\bigfrown{PQRSPQ}

%\setlength{\mywidth}{0pt}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{PQR}
\bigfrown{PQR}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user12290: You are welcome. Glad it helped.