Arc over several letters
Help please. I need to make it so that an arc can be placed over several letters (the picture shows how it should look). I need this code to work in 


See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86045/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222468/36296 helps (with a smile instead of a frown)
